# DRF+VueJS pagination wrong number of pages

Tags: django, vue.js, django-rest-framework, bootstrap-vue

I am trying to use `DRF` pagination backend and `VueJs Frontend`. I am trying to create pagination links but until now i only get first number. I have added `PageNumberPagination` to my `settings.py`. After articles `viewset`:

```
class ArticleViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Article.objects.all()
    lookup_field = "slug"
    serializer_class = ArticleSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, IsAuthorOrReadOnly]
    pagination_class = PageNumberPagination
```

I have used `Bootstrap-Vue` [Pagination](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/pagination/)

```
<div class="col" id="article-list" :articles="articles" v-for="article in articles" :key="article.pk" 
      :per-page="perPage"
      :current-page="currentPage">...</div>

<b-pagination
          v-model="currentPage"
          :total-rows="rows"
          :per-page="perPage"
          aria-controls="articles-list"
        ></b-pagination>
```

and `VueJS` script:

```
export default {
  name: "ArticleList",
  components: {
    HelloWorld,
  } ,
  data() {
    return  {
        articles: [],
        next: null,
        loadingArticles: false,
        perPage: 2,
        currentPage: 1,
        size:2,


    }
  },

  methods: {

  getArticles() {
          this.loadingArticles = true;
          let url = "http://localhost:8000/api/articles";
          axios.get(url)
                .then(response => {
                    this.articles = response.data.results;
            });
        },

    },
    computed: {
        rows() {
            console.log(this.articles.length);
            return this.articles.length;

        }
    },

    created() {
        this.getArticles();
    },
};
```

If i check the api address in the browser, I can see the next and previous data.

```
{
    "count": 4,
    "next": "http://localhost:8000/api/articles/?page=2",
    "previous": null,
    "results": [...]
}
```

How do I change the data of total-rows to make pagination work? Thanks

Comment: Did u find a solution to this question?Please share how you worked around it

Comment: yes I have found the solution. please explain details of your request, I wont miss some parts by that.

Comment: Thanks. My next link in vueJs isn't loading new items.The first page only loaded the number indicated in my views.py page_size, the same items show even when I click next, meaning new items are not loading

Comment: I am putting my function to get fetch articles.

Comment: Can you explain more please

Comment: yes but this is up to load more button, If you need pagination links I have to see your code also. I will add the button to get more, you will call fetchArticles or getArticles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply I added my next to fetching articles, I answer my question as to request, I now use vuex but VueJs is also similar:

```
fetchArticles (context) {
    context.commit("fetchStart");
    let endpoint = "articles/"

    if (context.state.next) {
      endpoint = context.state.next;
    }

    return ApiService.get(endpoint)
        .then(data=>{
          console.log(data);

          context.commit("setArticles", data.data.results)
          if (data.data.next) {
            context.commit("setNext", data.data.next);
          } else {
            context.commit("setNext", null)
          }
        })
        .catch((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        context.commit("setError", response.data.errors)
      })
  },
```

from my vuetemplate I call it for eg:

```
<script>
import { mapGetters, mapActions} from "vuex";
export default {
    name: "Articles",
    computed: {
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions(['articles/fetchArticles']),
    getArticles() {
        return this.$store.dispatch('articles/fetchArticles');
    },
  },
  created() {
    this.$store.dispatch('articles/fetchArticles').
    then(() => {
            this.isLoading = false;
    })
  }
};
</script>
```

and my button

```
      <li class="page-item disabled">
            <button
            v-show="next"
            @click="getArticles"
            class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"
        >Devamı...</button>
        </li>
```